# Shortest way to extract Map from List in Java

Tags: java, collections, java-7, guava

I have a List

```
List<FeatureHolder> featureHolderList;
```

consisting of FeatureHolder objects

```
public class FeatureHolder {
   private String  flag;
   private String  value;
}
```

Now I need to extract Map from the featureSetList. The solution is, of course, trivial:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(FeatureHolder fh: featureHolderList){
        map.put(fh.getFlag(), fh.getValue());
    }
```

The question is, **is there a better (shorter) way of doing this in Java 7**? I have looked into e.g. Google Collections and the method [Maps.uniqueIndex](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#uniqueIndex(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function)), but the code required to perform the transformation this way would be much longer, and arguably less readable.

Comment: Why not stick to the trivial solution until you upgrade to Java 8 (which offers one liner solution with the Streams API)?

Comment: just one remark `featureSetList` is it a `Set` or `List` ?? those are to notion completely different.... why call it like this ?

Comment: Eran: you're right, the solution is acceptable. I asked the question in the chance that there is a better way - this way both the SO community and I can learn something.

Comment: OSrys: variable names amended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often I find the decision whether to use Guava or not difficult. According to the Guava's own [caveats docu](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained#Caveats), you should refrain from using Guava, if there is no **net saving of lines of code** or a clear performance benefit.

However, in your case I fail to see an easy way to create your Map with Guava at the first place, since [Maps.uniqueIndex](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#uniqueIndex(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) only comes with a key mapping function, but no value mapping function. This means, you would end up with a map of type `Map<String, FeatureHolder>`.

If you can use Java 8, [Collectors.toMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) could be an option, but in my option nothing can't beat your "plain old 3 lines of easy to read code" solution, so **please stick to it!**

Answer (score 5):

with Java 7, your code is fine.

or you can use Java 8

```
Map<String, Item> map = list.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getKey,
                                                  item -> item));
```

Comment: instead of item->item you can write "Function.identity()"  (it does the same thing, but maybe you like better how it looks)

Comment: This can't be right as there must be a 'flag' and a 'value'. Maybe the OP updated the question in the meantime...

Answer (score 0):

You code is just fine, it's unlikely that you can do it shorter in Java 7. Just to make it a little more optimal you may add a default capacity for `HashMap` if you expect that all flags are different:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(fhList.size());
```

It's a little bit longer, but may work faster as rehashing will not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google collections

```
Map<String, String> map = Maps.uniqueIndex(yourList, Functions.toStringFunction());
```

Comment: please, I can't find `Maps` in Java 8 api doc ... in which package is it ?

Comment: its in Gauva library - http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html

Comment: This would not work, as it returns a Map<String, FeatureHolder> object - I need a Map<String, String> returned. Besides, the FeatureHolder.toString function does not return the string property of FeatureHolder, so even the map keys would not be correct.